# Generating a Signature Value in python

Tags: python-3.x, sha256

So the documentation i am looking at says to generate a Signature Value with C#,  however I am wanting to do the whole thing in Python  here is the information they have given me,  however the expected result is Signature: `wpGKFbhcBl+8JLVXGP0QqBooK6dtLBv9bYtI15NXL1U=` for SHA256, I am returning `b'YzI5MThhMTViODVjMDY1ZmJjMjRiNTU3MThmZDEwYTgxYTI4MmJhNzZkMmMxYmZkNmQ4YjQ4ZDc5MzU3MmY1NQ=='`

Can someone point me into the right direction?

```
var bytesToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TimeStamp.GetUnixTime() + transactionId + apiKey);
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(GetHashAlgorithm(Algorithm).ComputeHash(bytesToHash));
```

**My code:**

```
import hashlib
import base64
epochTime = 1547498533216
transactionId = "07643622"
APIKey = "13f1fd1b-ab2d-4c1f-8e2c-ca61878f2a44"
hash256 = bytes(str(epochTime) + transactionId + APIKey,'utf-8')
print(hash256)
signature = base64.b64encode(bytes(hashlib.sha256(hash256).hexdigest(),'utf-8'))
print(signature)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only problem is that you encoded the `hexdigest` (a string form that displays each byte as two characters in the `0-9a-f` range, which would be used as an alternative to base64 for making a human readable hash, not in combination with it), not the `digest` (the raw bytes of the SHA256 hash). Change:

```
signature = base64.b64encode(bytes(hashlib.sha256(hash256).hexdigest(),'utf-8'))
```

to:

```
signature = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(hash256).digest())
```

and the output is as you expect: `b'wpGKFbhcBl+8JLVXGP0QqBooK6dtLBv9bYtI15NXL1U='`

Answer (score 3):

hexdigest() contains only hexadecimal digits. You need to return the digest of the strings passed

```
import hashlib
import base64

epochTime = 1547498533216
transactionId = "07643622"
APIKey = "13f1fd1b-ab2d-4c1f-8e2c-ca61878f2a44"

signature = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(
    (str(epochTime) + transactionId + APIKey).encode()
).digest())

print( signature.decode() )
# wpGKFbhcBl+8JLVXGP0QqBooK6dtLBv9bYtI15NXL1U=
```

Comment: The `hmac` module isn't necessary here (it simplifies the code a titch, that's it); their only problem was using `hexdigest` instead of `digest` (which you fixed without calling attention to the change, a reason for avoid code-only answers).